# Proper handling of multiple sequential state updates

Tags: javascript, immutability, reactjs

This example is a bit contrived, but bear with me. Say I have two functions as members in a React component:

```
var OrderApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selectedOrders: {},
            selectedLineItems: {}
        };
    },

    setOrderSelected: function(order, newSelectedState) {
        var mutation = {};
        mutation[order.id] = {$set: newSelectedState};
        var newSelectedOrders = React.addons(this.state.selectedOrders, mutation);
        _.each(order.lineItems, function(lineItem) {
            setLineItemSelected(lineItem, newSelectedState);
        });
        this.setState({selectedOrders: newSelectedOrders});
    },

    setLineItemSelected: function(lineItem, newSelectedState) {
        var mutation = {};
        mutation[lineItem.id] = {$set: newSelectedState};
        var newSelectedLineItems = React.addons(this.state.selectedLineItems, mutation);
        this.setState({seelctedLineItems: newSelectedLineItems});
    }
});
```

At the completion of calling OrderApp.setOrderSelected(order, true), only the last lineItem selected state appears to have changed in my component's state. I'm guessing this is because React is batching the calls to setState, and so when I'm calling:

```
var newSelectedLineItems = React.addons(this.state.selectedLineItems, mutation);
```

in the second function, I'm picking up the original state each time, and so only the last mutation takes effect.

Should I be collecting all of the state mutations in the parent function and only calling setState once? This feels a bit clunky to me, and I'm wondering if I'm missing a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never be calling `this.setState` more than once in a given thread of execution within a component.

So you have a couple of options:

**Use forceUpdate instead of setState**

You don't HAVE to use `this.setState` - you can modify the state directly and use `this.forceUpdate` after you're done.

The main thing to remember here is that you should treat `this.state` as tainted as soon as you start modifying it directly.  IE: don't use the state, or properties you know you've modified until after you've called `this.forceUpdate`.  This isn't usually a problem.

I absolutely prefer this method when, you're dealing with nested objects within `this.state`.  Personally I'm not a huge fan of `React.addons.update` because I find the syntax extremely clunky.  I prefer to modify directly and `forceUpdate`.

**Create an object that you pass around until finally using it in setState**

Collect an object of all your changes, to pass to `this.setState` at the end of your thread of execution.

Comment: This mess with all the app logic, nothing shows up when using forceUpdate

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a problem with shallow merge.  You do have to collect the updates, and apply them at one time.

> feels a bit clunky to me

This is a really good sign that you should be using a mixin!  This code looks pretty terrible, but you can just pretend it looks pretty when you're using it.

```js
var React = require('react/addons');
var UpdatesMixin = {
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.__updates_list = [];
    },
    addUpdate: function(update){
        this.__updates_list.push(update);
        if (this.__updates_list.length === 1) {
         process.nextTick(function(){
          if (!this.isMounted()) {
            this.__updates_list = null;
            return;
          }

          var state = this.__updates_list.reduce(function(state, update){
            return React.addons.update(state, update);
          }, this.state);

          this.setState(state);
          this.__updates_list = [];     
        }.bind(this));
      }
    }
};
```

[requirebin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=b69c2899fed72eb06967)

It buffers all updates that occur synchronously, applies them to this.state, and then does a setState.

The usage looks like this (see the requirebin for a full demo).

```js
this.addUpdate({a: {b: {$set: 'foo'}};
this.addUpdate({a: {c: {$set: 'bar'}};
```

There are some places it could be optimized (by merging the updates objects, for example), but you can do that later without changing your components.

Comment: Being brand new to React, I hadn't considered using a Mixin here, but this definitely feels much cleaner. My one question involves the call to process.nextTick in your solution. The only documentation I can find suggests that this is a Node specific library. Is there a similar library that I can use to buffer the updates when processing on the client?

Comment: If you're not using browserify/webpack, you can download a standalone shim: http://wzrd.in/standalone/process%2fbrowser - most people do use cjs modules, and you'll have to compile some libraries yourself because npm is often the only distribution medium.

Comment: I really liked your answers to my question. I marked Mike's answer as accepted only because it requires no external dependencies. I think there's a strong case to be made that your answer approaches the problem from a more ReactJS mindset though. Thanks for the help.